# Show a fundamental group is infinite and nonabelian

Tags: algebraic-topology

Please help me prove this:

> Suppose *U,V* and *A=U $\bigcap$ V* are path connected open subsets of *X=U $\bigcup V$*. Suppose that *$\pi _{1}A= \mathbb{Z}_{2}$*, *$\pi _{1}U= \mathbb{Z}_{3}$* and *$\pi _{1}V= \mathbb{Z}_{4}$*. Then show that *$\pi_{1}X$* is infinite and nonabelian.

I guess we could use Van Kampen's theorem, but I don't what to do next.

Comment: Use van kampen to write down a presentation of your group. Then your question is really “how do I show that the group G is nonabelian?” In this case it will be easier to help once we can see what is confusing you

Comment: There might be something I'm missing here, but what's your injection from $\pi_1(U\bigcap V)=\mathbb{Z}_2$ to $\pi_1(U) = \mathbb{Z}_3$?

Comment: @StevenStadnicki -- There might be something _I'm_ missing here, but is there a reason $\pi_1(U \cap V) \to \pi_1(U)$ has to be an injection? If you glue a disk to a loop, we can kill that loop in the fundamental group using van kampen, since $\pi_1(D^2) = 1$. But here the map from $\pi_1(D^2 \cap X) = \langle \text{the loop we want to kill} \rangle$ to $1$ is not injective.